# How do you force text to line break and maintain centered positioning?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the "SHOP NOW" to be two different lines and centered?

Here is my relevant code:

```
.popover{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1500;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: impact;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    opacity: .8;
}
.pb1{
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 238px;
}

<div class="popover pb1" ><br/>SHOP NOW</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style

```
.pb2{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Change the content to be like this

```
<div class="popover pb1" >
    <div class="pb2">SHOP<br /> NOW</div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually figured it out right after you answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `span` tag. Check the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QsPP7/).